# How can I set classpath in Mac Os for Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, macos

I know that I need to set JAVA_HOME & CLASSPATH both before use selenium webdriver but How can I do that in MAC Os?

I have checked my export command and articles related to it but not sure how it works. It is easy with windows os but seems hard to set in MAC Os.

I want to set following in MAC Os AS I did in window :

JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40

CLASSPATH = C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51\bin

Comment: what happen if you go to a terminal and type `echo $JAVA_HOME` ?

Comment: it returns nothing , I have just installed java and finding option to set classpath..

Comment: Have you installed a JDK or a JRE?

Comment: Ok, and where is located your java SDK ?

Comment: I have just installed java from here : `https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_install.xml` , now really confuse that where it's all files are? so I can get path at least.

Comment: @Thomas - How can I find those installed files of JAVA ? I mean where is those? For example :  in window os we get all files in program files.

Comment: So that's a JRE you have there. JAVA_HOME is meaningless when you don't have a JDK. You can set CLASSPATH, but it actually should *not* point to the `bin` directory. So you were doing something wrong on your Windows machine. So let's retract and ask - why do you need those variables?

Comment: @RealSkeptic - As per selenium webdriver steps it need JAVA_HOME and classpath to be set.

Comment: Steps where? Can you link? They don't specify the steps by operating system? Anyway, if they insist on JAVA_HOME it means they require that you install the JDK, not the JRE.

Comment: Yes I know that require JDK but that is as JAVA_HOME , JRE we need in CLASSPATH variable.

Comment: I seriously doubt that they need you to install both a JDK and a JRE for Selenium, as the JDK includes a JRE. And as I said, a CLASSPATH that points to the `bin` directory of the JRE doesn't make sense. Where is that link? Add it to your question.

Comment: @RealSkeptic - Yes you are right , I just need to JDK to set as classpath for variable JAVA_HOME , but how can I do set that in mac? can you please let me know?

Comment: Note: download the **JDK** from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90277/discussion-between-helping-hands-and-realskeptic).